# Since minority carriers drives leakage current in PN junctions, why do people put minority carriers in semiconductors?

Tags: semiconductor-physics

Since minority carriers drives leakage current in PN junctions, why do people put minority charge carriers in semiconductors ? Why not putting only majority charge carriers ?

Is it because technically, this would be difficult and it would be expensive ?

Comment: In a semiconductor, $np$ is a constant. You always have minority carriers. No way around it.

Comment: People don't put minority carriers in semiconductors.

Comment: Hello, you say np is constant : do you mean because we have a *junction*, or do you mean that even without a junction PN there is np=constant. For example, in the P semiconductor, there is np=constant, and in the N semiconductor, there is np=constant ? Where are the minority carriers coming from ? If you put T=0K, no light, nothing, I don't see where there are coming from ?

Comment: @MathieuKrisztian - in equilibrium, $np$ is constant whether it is intrinsic, p-type, or n-type. Ignore T=0K, that is a pathological situation since in an intrinsic semiconductor you won't have any net carriers (and in a doped semiconductor none of dopants will be activated). Without minority carriers, bipolar transistors would not work.

Comment: Thank you. Everything is clear. But there is a last problem. Let's consider a N semiconductor. The majority carriers are the electrons. Now the problem : since whenever there is a mobile electron charge carrier, there is an equivalent hole, why do we say that the electrons are "majority charge carriers", since by definition, there are as many holes as electrons, thus are the holes (minority carriers) really in "minority" ? Thank you